# Common class for indexing an array to a map by IDs

Tags: java, dictionary

I got lot of cases in my code where I have to access data from a DB using Hibernate and receive the results as a list. Most often this data is cached and accessed by ID. So obviously, I have to convert it into a Map for quick results, as iterating over it every time would be an O(n) nightmare.

The question isn't how to do that, the process is fairly trivial:

```
Map<Integer, ProjectEntry> projectEntries = new HashMap<>();
for (ProjectEntry p : projectService.listProjectEntries()) {
    projectEntries.put(p.getId(), p);
}
```

What I wonder is if there's already a feature for this in common Java libraries, because I have to repeat this code over and over and would love to reduce it to a single line. It seems like such a common use case.

Comment: Write it yourself as a method and then invoke that method.  It's on a single line now.

Comment: I've already outsourced it to a utility class, but I can't believe there's no commons library to already support this. That was my question.

Comment: You mean getting a map straight from `Hibernate`?

Comment: Does Hibernate already support that? I always get the results by invoking `.list()` at a Hibernate Criteria.

Comment: There is no `projectService.getProjectEntryById`? Generally hibernate already caches.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by sajib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51675278/3182664) might be the proper one if the built-in functionality of Hibernate already can solve this for you.

Otherwise, such a map can be created using the built-in functionality of the Java standard API - namely, using the appropriate `Collector`:

```
Map<Integer, ProjectEntry> map = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(ProjectEntry::getId, Function.identity()));
```

But of course, this is clumsy. You could pull it out into a utility method. And this utility method could be rather generic, wrapping the line shown above, with a minor specialization for the `ProjectEntry` class.

A small example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapById
{
    static class ProjectEntry
    {
        int getId()
        {
            return System.identityHashCode(this);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<ProjectEntry> list = new ArrayList<ProjectEntry>();
        list.add(new ProjectEntry());
        list.add(new ProjectEntry());
        list.add(new ProjectEntry());

        System.out.println(createMapFromIds(list));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, ProjectEntry> createMapFromIds(
        Collection<? extends ProjectEntry> collection)
    {
        return createMap(collection, ProjectEntry::getId);
    }

    private static <K, T> Map<K, T> createMap(
        Collection<? extends T> collection, 
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper)
    {
        return collection.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, Function.identity()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List<Map<String,Object>> dataList = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is caching in the database engine, in hibernate. So maps seem a further caching layer. Still it might be outside the hibernate session and no O/R mapping, being more efficient.

```
Map<Integer, ProjectEntry> projectEntries = 
        projectService.listProjectEntries().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProjectEntry::getId, Function.identity()));
```

If you need many maps, reconsider whether not a DOM, **document object model** is concerned:

- having many entities forming one large object graph (maybe "Project"), more or less forming one single *document*;
- references only to main data, not to other projects;
- queries only inside the project;
- slow processing, involving a cascade of UPDATEs over several hierarchical entities.

In that case a database might not be the best way to hold the "document." In one project we turned that graph into an XML document using **JAXB** and stored the document as BLOB of GZipped compressed XML in a single table. The document object model then can have one top element with lists and especially maps.

It made processing much easier, and faster.

JPA hides much, but if you feel the need of many maps, reconsider the architecture.